# Easy comparison between table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using DataTables JQuery plugins and I would like to ask the following two questions.

- Is it possible to have MIN or MAX or AVG values calculated (dynamically) at the end of each column?

  For example:

  > A/A    A    B    C
  >
  > L1     2    3    4
  >
  > L2     3    4    5

  If I would like to prin line 3 with the Min Values of each columnt should have been:

  > L3     2    3    4
- Is it possible to create another column D which will contain the result of a formula for each row? For example `Di = Ai + Bi`?

  According to the above example the resulted table should be the following:

  > L1  2    3    4    5
  >
  > L2  3    4    5    7

Can I somehow perform those operations through DataTables or I have to prepare the data before passing it to the DataTables?

Thanks.

PS:

I suppose I need something similar to this [trirand.net/examples/grid/functionality/footer/default.aspx](http://trirand.net/examples/grid/functionality/footer/default.aspx) but for DataTables plugin. In addition to that I need some formulas for rows as well. – salamis just now edit

Comment: This is very nice, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: I only have the tables but unfortunately I do not know how to proceed or if there is a plugin for this functionality.

Comment: I suppose I need something similar to this http://www.trirand.net/examples/grid/functionality/footer/default.aspx but for DataTables plugin. In addition to that I need some formulas for rows as well.

Comment: I think you need to do it manually like making a new row/column and calculating the values yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mRender ( http://datatables.net/ref#mRender ) for the last column. mRender, when used as a function, has access the the data source object for the row (third parameter), so you can easily do a quick sum and then return the calculated value :-).

Comment: What about the ability of doing Excel Formula Like calculations and adding another column?